# Ag-grid : GroupByColum Sort not working for numeric values, it provides only a string sort

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In my ag-grid , when I do a group by a column , and I click to sort the groups are sorted alphabetically  even for numeric values.

Is there a way to provide a comparator that depends on group by (row group) column type ?

**To reproduce the issue :** 
1. In punker bellow, try to group by Age row
2. Sort by Group with asc or Desc sort
3. Group is are sorted by alphabetic sort not by values (age order when sort desc is : 15,16,17,18,19,2,20,200,21,22....) !

link : https://plnkr.co/edit/FjJOYQgsz46KDQfoNCQF?p=preview

```js
    export class AppComponent {
      private gridApi;
      private gridColumnApi;

      private columnDefs;
      private defaultColDef;
      private sideBar;
      private frameworkComponents;
      private rowData: [];

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.columnDefs = [
          {
            field: "athlete",
            width: 150,
            filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            field: "age",
            width: 90,
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            field: "country",
            width: 120,
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            field: "year",
            width: 90,
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            field: "date",
            width: 110
          },
          {
            field: "gold",
            width: 100,
            filter: false
          },
          {
            field: "silver",
            width: 100,
            filter: false
          },
          {
            field: "bronze",
            width: 100,
            filter: false
          },
          {
            field: "total",
            width: 100,
            filter: false
          }
        ];
        this.defaultColDef = { filter: true, sortable: true, enableRowGroup : true };
        this.sideBar = {
          toolPanels: [
            {
              id: "columns",
              labelDefault: "Columns",
              labelKey: "columns",
              iconKey: "columns",
              toolPanel: "agColumnsToolPanel"
            },
            {
              id: "filters",
              labelDefault: "Filters",
              labelKey: "filters",
              iconKey: "filter",
              toolPanel: "agFiltersToolPanel"
            },
            {
              id: "customStats",
              labelDefault: "Custom Stats",
              labelKey: "customStats",
              iconKey: "custom-stats",
              toolPanel: "customStatsToolPanel"
            }
          ],
          defaultToolPanel: "customStats"
        };
        this.frameworkComponents = { customStatsToolPanel: CustomStatsToolPanel };
      }

      onGridReady(params) {
        this.gridApi = params.api;
        this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

        this.http
          .get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinners.json")
          .subscribe(data => {
            data[10].age = 200;
            data[12].age = 2;
            this.rowData = data;

          });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any solution

Answer (score 6):

It seems like ag-Grid uses the default JavaScript's sorting definition, which is why it might not work for numbers or any other data types. You will have to pass it a [custom comparator function](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#custom-sorting) to the `comparator` property in your column definitions.

I am assuming you only need to use that function for the age column.

On the code below, I have added `numberSort`, which is the comparator function for the age column.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  const numberSort = (num1: number, num2: number) => {
    return num1 - num2;
  };
  this.columnDefs = [{
      field: "athlete",
      width: 150,
      filter: "agTextColumnFilter",
      sortable: true,
    },
    {
      field: "age",
      width: 90,
      sortable: true,
      comparator: numberSort
    },
    .
    .
    .
    // other column defs
  ];
  this.defaultColDef = {
    filter: true,
    sortable: true,
    enableRowGroup: true
  };

}
```

I have forked your demo and added my changes over [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/QX1VM2KyQh3Umg9eLcXz?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for response, but it's not what i have explain. Age sort is already working, but when you group by age and sort group  it doesn't work !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today. I found that you can create a custom sort comparator for row groups from the documentation in this article:

https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/angular/grouping/

In this documentation they mention `gridOptions.autoGroupColumnDef.comparator`. I modified their example comparator to also work with numeric values. It ends up looking like:

```js
autoGroupColumnDef = {
  comparator: function (valueA, valueB) {
    if (valueA == null) return -1;
    if (valueB == null) return 1;
    if (!valueA.substring || !valueB.substring) return valueA - valueB;
    if (valueA.length < 1 || valueB.length < 1) return valueA - valueB;
    if (!isNaN(valueA) && !isNaN(valueB)) {
      // values will come in as strings
      return Number(valueA) - Number(valueB);
    }
    return valueA < valueB ? -1 : valueA > valueB ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

I've modified your plnkr to add in this and you can see the row groups sorting correctly.

https://plnkr.co/edit/OnB2pd2qCLKj5DxU?preview

Comment: Solid solution for strings. Nice function!